# explain plan meanings in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i use explain plan,but i am confused what is its real meaning.

```
explain extended 
select * 
from (select type_id from con_consult_type cct  
      where cct.consult_id = (select id 
                              from con_consult 
                              where id = 1)) 
      cctt left join con_type ct on cctt.type_id = ct.id;
```

the results is 
[image]

i google the derived is temporary table,but what is its sql of the temporary table?is ctt table?
and the step 2,is result of `cctt left join con_type ct on cctt.type_id = ct.id`?
the FK_CONSULT_TO_CONSULT_TYPE is consult_id refer con_consult id column,
how to use the index in the sql?
get all results of ctt,and then use the index filter?

please help me explain what the explain meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad query to learn the basics of the `explain` output, there is simply too much happening with all the sub queries, and joins.

I can give a run down of some of the essentials;

- 'rows' column: Less is better, it shows how many rows had to be scanned by the database, anything less than a couple of hundred is good, generally indicates how well it is able to find your data from the indexes;
- 'possible_keys': and 'keys': If 'rows' is big, you may have to tweek your keys to provide the engine with some help finding your data
- 'type': Type of join

To answer some of your questions;

- 'sql of the temporary table' - it's the first subquery in your sql
- With `FK_CONSULT_TO_CONSULT_TYPE` you dont have to do anything, the engine has allready picked this up as an index which is what the explain is saying.
- Queries are broken into 3 essentials steps; select data, filter, and join. Each row in the explain is a detail into one or more of these operations, it may not necessarily relate to a specific section of your SQL as the engine may have combined various parts into one.